# JQuery: How to select all elements except input and textarea? (to disable keydown event)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to disable the backspace key in my jQuery app, so that it does not cause the browser to go back a page. However, I do not want to disable it if an input or textarea element is focused, because I want backspace to work properly there.

So, I want to select anything that is not an input or textarea.

Here is the code. The problem is that it fires for every element, even inputs and textareas.

```
    $(':not(input, textarea)').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I do not understand why the :not() function is not working. Is there a better way I can do this?

Note that if I remove the :not() function, it works properly. That is, it only fires for input and textarea elements.

EDIT: Based on the accepted answer, here is code that works. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var element = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (element != 'input' && element != 'textarea') {
        if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for putting the correct code at the bottom. This problem has been killin me for days, thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `keydown` event bubbles from the `<input>` or `<textarea>` element to the normal element that contains it, firing the event from that element.

You need to check `e.target`.

Comment: ...and preferably bind to `document` or `html` rather than every element separately.

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
$("*:not(input)")
```