# Implementing key press with JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I want on a key press an alert box will get displayed. It is done. But the problem is I have a textbox inside the page and when I am trying typing inside the textbox then also the alert box is coming.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.key == "F8") {
            alert('Right key pressed');
        } else {
            alert("Error key pressed")
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639956/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-except-input-and-textarea-to-disable-keydow

Comment: That looks like incredibly annoying functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbox is element of your `document` so it is good behavior that it raise `document`'s events.

You should add handler to textbox to [stop propagate](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) event to `document` layer

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, remember though that e.stopPropagation() is IE9 and above.
If you plan to support IE8 maybe do `e.stopPropagation = e.stopPropagation || function(){e.cancelBubble = true}`

Comment: @GeorgeNemes - jQuery handles all of that for you.

Comment: Yeah you're right, jQuery handles that and he's using it. Force of habit. I'll leave the comment for vanilla javascript reference, maybe it will help somebody. Thanks

Comment: @suvroc. If I want the same output using "alt+f" instead of "F8" tyhn what should I do? I tried with the following but failed. ``if (e.key = "F" && e.altKey) {``

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using event listeners:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var keyListner = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key == 'F8') {
        console.log('Right key pressed');
    } else {
        console.log('Error key pressed')
    };
}

//  Set the event listener
$(document).on('keyup', 'body', keyListner);

// Disable it on focus
$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
    $(document).off('keyup', 'body', keyListner);
});

// Enable it on blur
$('input, textarea').blur(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', 'body', keyListner);
});
});
```